# Table cell take minimum possible width

Tags: html, html-table, tablelayout

In `table` with `table-layout` set to `auto` & `width: 100%`, is it possible to instruct column/table cells to take least width possible? For instance, I have a column with three action buttons with `white-space:nowrap`, and I would like this column/cells to take exactly enough width to show three buttons in one line.

Another approach would to to instruct one column to take max possible width.

Comment: What you describe is the normal behavior in that layout. So if your code behaves different you must have changed the default rendering. you will have to add your (reduced) code for us to help. And you will get plus points if you create a jsfiddle with it!

Comment: What if you have table that has 1000px width, and 2 columns. Both would take 50% width right ? But I would like to first column take min width, and second to take the rest.

Comment: Ah, so you force fixed width? You did not say so in your question. In that case have a try setting the columns width to 0% versus 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the widths of the columns to 0% versus 100%. The rendering engines will automatically widen the narrow column(s) as required to fit the content.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/nog2oqjx/

Markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button>1</button>
            <button>2</button>
            <button>3</button>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Styles:

```
table { width: 100%; }
tr  { width: 100%; }
td { width: 0%; background-color: green; padding: 10px; }
td:last-of-type { width: 100%; background-color: yellow; }
button { width: 40px;}
```

Comment: `width: 0%` breaks layout in Firefox.  `width: 1%` and `width: 0px` both work to reduce col size to minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting some margins to zero.

```css
button {
  margin: 0px;  
  }

td {
  margin: 0px;  
  }
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button">Button 1
      <button type="button">Button 2
      <button type="button">Button 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```